# Forcing application/json MIME type in a view (Flask)

Tags: python, json, mime-types, flask

I can't figure out how to force the MIME type `application/json` for a view in Flask. Here is a simple view I've thrown together for demonstration purposes:

```
@app.route("/")
def testView():
    ret = '{"data": "JSON string example"}'
    return ret
```

The JSON string (held in variable `ret`) is gathered from elsewhere (using stdout from another program using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)) so I can't use [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.jsonify) provided with Flask.

I've had a look at the ["Returning Json" Documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#returning-json) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086448/) Stackoverflow question but I haven't had any luck so far. I've been looking around for awhile now & will continue searching but thought I'd ask here just in case anyone has come across this.

Thanks.

---

See the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11945643/586621)

The solution:

```
@app.route("/")
def testView():
    ret = '{"data": "JSON string example"}'

    resp = Response(response=ret,
                    status=200,
                    mimetype="application/json")

    return resp
```

I found this website useful: [Implementing a RESTful Web API with Python & Flask](http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Like [soulseekah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482864/soulseekah) noticed, [make_response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.make_response) is probably a better option in this case. Then set the mimetype property.

```
r = make_response( data )
r.mimetype = 'application/json'
return r
```

Comment: [`make_response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.make_response) is probably a better option in this case. Then set the `mimetype` property. `r = make_response( data ); r.mimetype = 'application/json'; return r`

Comment: The preceding should be turned into the correct answer!

Answer (score 50):

If you use:

```
from flask import jsonify
```

and then in your code:

```
return jsonify(somedict)
```

then jsonify() automatically sets the mime type to 'application/json'

Edit:

This was ***previously*** considered a risk, but not anymore, and Flask has also updated its recommendation: *"ECMAScript 5 closed this vulnerability, so only extremely old browsers are still vulnerable. All of these browsers have other more serious vulnerabilities, so this behavior was changed and jsonify() now supports serializing arrays."* http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/security/#json-security

Comment: What do you do for arrays?

Comment: No, I mean what you do for sending JSON array responses? (Let's say I have a Python array, I'll render it as JSON array that begins with `[` and ends with `]`. What do you do then?

Comment: Try jsonify([1,2,3]) it will give you error. jsonify(somearr) doesn't exist.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan You should not return plain list in a JSON service for security reasons. So flask makes it intentionally difficult. This is documented in detail here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/security/#json-security

Comment: Flask has now changed its recommendations: *"ECMAScript 5 closed this vulnerability, so only extremely old browsers are still vulnerable. All of these browsers have other more serious vulnerabilities, so this behavior was changed and jsonify() now supports serializing arrays."* http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/security/#json-security @AhmetAlpBalkan