# Mysql data to be save as CSV/Excel using flask-python when button click

Tags: python, mysql, csv, flask, export

I'm new at exporting data, I research all over the net but it was really hard for me to understand, can someone help me to know the basic about it.

This is my main problem: I want to download a specific data from mysql base on the date range I choose in my client, then when I click the download button, I want these data from mysql to be save in my computer together the user have the option to save it as CSV/Excel, I'm using python for my webservice. Thank you

This is my code right know in my webservice:

```
@api.route('/export_file/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def export_file():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        selectAttendance = """SELECT * FROM attendance"""
        db.session.execute(selectAttendance)
        db.session.commit()


        f = csv.writer(open("file.csv", "w"))
        for row in selectAttendance:
            f.writerow([str(row)])





    return jsonify({'success': True})
```

Comment: You should tell us which web framework you are using. I assume this is flask.

Comment: Sorry I forget to include it, yes I'm I'm using flask, I edit my heading now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:

1. Set the <strike>mime header</strike> "Content-Type" part of the http header to the corresponding [MIME-Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) matching your data.
   This tells the browser what type of data the webserver is going to send.
2. Send the actual data in the 'body'

With flask:

[Forcing application/json MIME type in a view (Flask)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945523/forcing-application-json-mime-type-in-a-view-flask/11945643#11945643)

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/

Comment: Hi thank you for this. It helps me a lot especially with the content header. I can save now my data. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get(self):
    try:
        os.stat(BACKUP_PATH)
    except:
        os.mkdir(BACKUP_PATH)
    now = datetime.now() # current date and time
    year = now.strftime("%Y")
    month = now.strftime("%m")
    day = now.strftime("%d")
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    date_time = now.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H:%M:%S")
    TODAYBACKUPPATH = BACKUP_PATH + '/' + date_time

    try:
        os.stat(TODAYBACKUPPATH)
    except:
        os.mkdir(TODAYBACKUPPATH)
    print ("checking for databases names file.")

    if os.path.exists(DB_NAME):
        file1 = open(DB_NAME)
        multi = 1
        print ("Databases file found...")
        print ("Starting backup of all dbs listed in file " + DB_NAME)
    else:
        print ("Databases file not found...")
        print ("Starting backup of database " + DB_NAME)
        multi = 0

    if multi:
        in_file = open(DB_NAME,"r")
        flength = len(in_file.readlines())
        in_file.close()
        p = 1
        dbfile = open(DB_NAME,"r")

        while p <= flength:
            db = dbfile.readline()   # reading database name from file
            db = db[:-1]         # deletes extra line
            dumpcmd = "mysqldump -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + db + " > " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + db + ".sql"
            os.system(dumpcmd)
            gzipcmd = "gzip " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + db + ".sql"
            os.system(gzipcmd)
            p = p + 1
        dbfile.close()
    else:
        db = DB_NAME
        dumpcmd = "mysqldump -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + db + " > " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + db + ".sql"
        os.system(dumpcmd)
        gzipcmd = "gzip " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + db + ".sql"
        os.system(gzipcmd)
        # t = ("Your backups have been created in '" + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "' directory")
        return "Your Folder have been created in '" + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "'."
```